# Start JBoss Fuse 6.1 inside Eclipse Luna with JBoss Tools

Tags: eclipse, osgi, jbossfuse, jboss-tools

I'm on to learn ESB, OSGi and JBoss Fuse. Recently I've downloaded the newest Fuse 6.1 server and the newest Eclipse Luna EE (4.4.2) and I've put a JBoss Tools in it. I've configured a Fuse 6.1 server in Eclipse.

The JBoss Fuse works well when I start with bin/fuse.bat .

But when I start the Fuse server inside Eclipse I've got a very long error message on the Eclipse console. The first and (I think) relevant part is below.

(I can start WildFly 8.1 server inside the Eclipse.)

After many tries I've added the following 3 lines to eclipse.ini, and the Fuse Server inside Eclipse uses the same JDK

```
-vm
c:\PROGRA~1\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin\javaw.exe
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
```

What have I to change?

Thx, Gábor

```
Please wait while JBoss Fuse is loading...
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exported package names cannot be zero length.
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.manifestparser.ManifestParser.normalizeExportClauses(ManifestParser.java:744)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.manifestparser.ManifestParser.<init>(ManifestParser.java:191)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.ExtensionManager.<init>(ExtensionManager.java:221)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.<init>(Felix.java:406)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkFactory.newFramework(FrameworkFactory.java:28)
    at org.apache.karaf.main.Main.launch(Main.java:310)
    at org.apache.karaf.main.Main.main(Main.java:537)
ERROR: Error parsing system bundle export statement: org.osgi.framework.startlevel;uses:="org.osgi.framework";version="1.0", org.osgi.framework.wiring;uses:="org.osgi.resource,org.osgi.framework";version="1.1", org.osgi.framework.hooks.bundle;uses:="org.osgi.framework";version="1.1", org.osgi.framework.hooks.service;uses:="org.osgi.framework";version="1.1", org.osgi.framework.hooks.resolver;uses:="org.osgi.framework.wiring";version="1.0", org.osgi.framework.launch;uses:="org.osgi.framework";version="1.1", org.osgi.framework.namespace;uses:="org.osgi.resource";version="1.0", org.osgi.framework;version="1.7",org.osgi.framework.hooks.weaving;uses:="org.osgi.framework.wiring";version="1.0",org.osgi.resource;version="1.0",org.osgi.service.url;version="1.0",org.osgi.service.startlevel;uses:="org.osgi.framework";version="1.1",org.osgi.service.packageadmin;uses:="org.osgi.framework";version="1.2",org.osgi.service.url;version="1.0", org.osgi.util.tracker;uses:="org.osgi.framework";version="1.5.1", org.apache.felix.framework.monitor;version="1.0", org.apache.karaf.jaas.boot;version="2.3.0.redhat-610379", org.apache.karaf.jaas.boot.principal;version="2.3.0.redhat-610379", org.apache.karaf.version;version="2.3.0.redhat-610379", org.apache.xalan.extensions; version="2.7.1", org.apache.xalan.xsltc.compiler; version="2.7.1", org.apache.xalan.xsltc.cmdline.getopt; version="2.7.1", org.apache.xalan.xsltc.util; version="2.7.1", org.apache.xalan.transformer; version="2.7.1", org.apache.xalan.xsltc.trax; version="2.7.1", org.apache.xalan.processor; version="2.7.1", org.apache.xalan.lib; version="2.7.1", org.apache.xalan.trace; version="2.7.1", org.apache.xalan.xsltc.compiler.util; version="2.7.1", org.apache.xalan.templates; version="2.7.1", org.apache.xalan.xsltc; version="2.7.1", org.apache.xalan.xsltc.runtime; version="2.7.1", org.apache.xalan; version="2.7.1", org.apache.xalan.xslt; version="2.7.1", org.apache.xalan.lib.sql; version="2.7.1", org.apache.xalan.xsltc.runtime.output; version="2.7.1", org.apache.xalan.xsltc.dom; version="2.7.1", org.apache.xalan.client; version="2.7.1", org.apache.xalan.xsltc.cmdline; version="2.7.1", org.apache.xalan.serialize; version="2.7.1", org.apache.xalan.res; version="2.7.1", org.apache.xml.dtm.ref; version="2.7.1", org.apache.xml.dtm; version="2.7.1", org.apache.xml.dtm.ref.sax2dtm; version="2.7.1", org.apache.xml.dtm.ref.dom2dtm; version="2.7.1", org.apache.xml.res; version="2.7.1", org.apache.xml.serializer.dom3; version="2.7.1", org.apache.xml.serializer; version="2.7.1", org.apache.xml.serializer.utils; version="2.7.1", org.apache.xml.utils.res; version="2.7.1", org.apache.xml.utils; version="2.7.1", org.apache.xpath.functions; version="2.7.1", org.apache.xpath.jaxp; version="2.7.1", org.apache.xpath.patterns; version="2.7.1", org.apache.xpath.objects; version="2.7.1", org.apache.xpath.res; version="2.7.1", org.apache.xpath; version="2.7.1", org.apache.xpath.axes; version="2.7.1", org.apache.xpath.compiler; version="2.7.1", org.apache.xpath.operations; version="2.7.1", org.apache.xpath.domapi; version="2.7.1", org.apache.html.dom; version="2.11.0", org.apache.wml.dom; version="2.11.0", org.apache.wml; version="2.11.0", org.apache.xerces.parsers; version="2.11.0", org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.models; version="2.11.0", org.apache.xerces.xni.parser; version="2.11.0", org.apache.xerces.impl.dv.xs; version="2.11.0", org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.traversers; version="2.11.0", org.apache.xerces.util; version="2.11.0", org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd; version="2.11.0", org.apache.xerces.jaxp.validation; version="2.11.0", org.apache.xerces.dom3.as; version="2.11.0", org.apache.xerces.impl.dv; version="2.11.0", org.apache.xerces.jaxp; version="2.11.0", org.apache.xerces.jaxp.datatype; version="2.11.0", org.apache.xerces.impl.xpath.regex; version="2.11.0", org.apache.xerces.xni; version="2.11.0", org.apache.xerces.impl.msg; version="2.11.0", org.apache.xerces.impl.dv.util; version="2.11.0", org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.util; version="2.11.0", org.apache.xerces.dom; version="2.11.0", org.apache.xerces.dom.events; version="2.11.0", org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.opti; version="2.11.0", org.apache.xerces.impl; version="2.11.0", org.apache.xerces.xs; version="2.11.0", org.apache.xerces.impl.io; version="2.11.0", org.apache.xerces.xpointer; version="2.11.0", org.apache.xerces.impl.dv.dtd; version="2.11.0", org.apache.xerces.xinclude; version="2.11.0", org.apache.xerces.impl.xpath; version="2.11.0", org.apache.xerces.xs.datatypes; version="2.11.0", org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.identity; version="2.11.0", org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.models; version="2.11.0", org.apache.xerces.xni.grammars; version="2.11.0", org.apache.xerces.impl.xs; version="2.11.0", org.apache.xerces.impl.validation; version="2.11.0", org.apache.xml.serialize; version="2.11.0", ,org.apache.karaf.branding, com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax, com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom, com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp, com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.xni, com.sun.jndi.ldap (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exported package names cannot be zero length.)
ERROR: Bundle org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn [1] Error starting mvn:org.ops4j.pax.url/pax-url-mvn/1.3.7 (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn [1]: Unable to resolve 1.0: missing requirement [1.0] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=javax.net.ssl))
ERROR: Bundle org.ops4j.pax.url.wrap [2] Error starting mvn:org.ops4j.pax.url/pax-url-wrap/1.3.7 (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle org.ops4j.pax.url.wrap [2]: Unable to resolve 2.0: missing requirement [2.0] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=javax.net.ssl))
ERROR: Bundle org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-service [3] Error starting mvn:org.ops4j.pax.logging/pax-logging-service/1.7.2 (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-service [3]: Unable to resolve 3.0: missing requirement [3.0] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=javax.xml.parsers))
ERROR: Bundle org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-api [4] Error starting mvn:org.ops4j.pax.logging/pax-logging-api/1.7.2 (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-api [4]: Unable to resolve 4.0: missing requirement [4.0] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=javax.xml.parsers))
ERROR: Bundle org.apache.geronimo.specs.geronimo-osgi-registry [151] Error starting mvn:org.apache.geronimo.specs/geronimo-osgi-registry/1.1 (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle org.apache.geronimo.specs.geronimo-osgi-registry [151]: Unable to resolve 151.0: missing requirement [151.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.osgi.framework)(version>=1.5.0)))
ERROR: Bundle org.apache.felix.configadmin [6] Error starting mvn:org.apache.felix/org.apache.felix.configadmin/1.4.0.redhat-610379 (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle org.apache.felix.configadmin [6]: Unable to resolve 6.0: missing requirement [6.0] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=javax.security.auth))
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn [1]: Unable to resolve 1.0: missing requirement [1.0] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=javax.net.ssl)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:4225)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2063)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1317)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:304)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know Fuse 6.1 is not compatible with Java 8. Are you sure you run it with Java 8 in your command line?

Comment: Thx! You're right.

In Eclipse everywhere can be set JDK8 but in the "Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs" section have to set JDK7 as the default JRE.

So, the eclipse.ini even the JBoss Fuse Runtime can point to JDK8. Stange.

Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Thx! You're right.

In Eclipse everywhere can be set JDK8 but **in the "Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs" section have to set JDK7 as the default JRE**.

So, the eclipse.ini even the JBoss Fuse Runtime can point to JDK8. Strange.

Thank you again!